# How to set Firebase rules / [FirebaseDatabase] Using an unspecified index

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "Recent": {
      ".indexOn": ["userID", "chatRoomID"]
    }
  }
}
```

Still I'm getting:

> [FirebaseDatabase] Using an unspecified index. Consider adding
>   ".indexOn": "chatroomID" at /Recent to your security rules for better
>   performance

How do I have to set it properly? I have tried the last 20 minutes, but can't get is right. Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rules say `".indexOn": ["userID", "chatRoomID"]` but your error says `chatroomID`.

chatroomID is not the same as chatRoomID.

Comment: will accept in minutes... thank you -.- stupid typo -.-

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Comment: Well spotted Mathew! Given that it's unlikely that a future developer making the same mistake will find this question/answer, I'm going to vote to close it as a typo.

Comment: Just trying to help, I have also voted it as a typo as well.